# Is there a Disable Click listener on Android?

Tags: java, android, button, toast, disable

I want to display a toast
when a disabled button click
Like "this button is disabled"

I tried

```
button1.setOnDisableClickListener
(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View _view) {
    SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "fdd");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set regular on click listener on the button, and inside it check if the button is clickable/disabled or whatever. Kotlin code may look like:

```
btnSelect.setOnClickListener {
        if (it.isClickable)
            doAction()
        else
            Toast.makeText(context, "The button is disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```